# textview into an SMS body Android

Tags: java, android, sms

I am making an application for Android where it displays your exact coordinates via GPS in a text view when you open the app.  You then press a button, and an SMS is sent to a preset number with your coordinates.  I have everything working, but the SMS body.  I can't figure out how to take the textview with your coordinates and have it send in the SMS body.  Any help would be awesome!

MAIN JAVA PAGE

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected LocationListener locationListener;
    protected Context context;
    TextView txtLat;
    String lat;
    String provider;
    protected String latitude,longitude; 
    protected boolean gps_enabled,network_enabled;
    Button button;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1000, this);




        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    try {

                        String messageToSend = "R.id.textview1";
                        String number = "8143664050";

                        SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(number, null, messageToSend, null,null);


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS failed!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        txtLat.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("Latitude","disable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("Latitude","enable");

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.d("Latitude","status");
    }

}
```

XML FILE

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:onClick="gotoActivity"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
String messageToSend = "R.id.textview1";
```

to this

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
String messageToSend = tv.getText().toString();
```

Comment: it worked! you saved me a bunch of headaches, thanks a bunch.